# Loop through class and create noUisliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nouislider

I have some code that loops through a class and makes for each class a `noUiSlider`.

I am trying to make the value's of the noUi slider clickable (set value), but its not working, I only get the last slider working.

javascript:

```
var sliders = $('.create-sliders');
for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {

    noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
        start: [ 0 ],
        range: {
            // start at 0 and end at 1000
            min: 0,
            max: 180
        },
        behaviour: 'snap',  
        connect: [true, false],
        //set values that are clickable
        pips: { mode: 'values', values: [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180] 
        },
    });
    sliders[i].noUiSlider.on('slide', addValues);
    let values = sliders[i].getElementsByClassName('noUi-value');
    for(let val of values){
        var testSlider = sliders[i];
        val.pip = val.innerHTML;
        val.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        val.onclick = (e) => {
            testSlider.noUiSlider.set(val.pip);
        }
    }
}

function addValues(){
    var allValues = [];
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="create-sliders"></div> 
<div class="create-sliders"></div> 
<div class="create-sliders"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @hani, just want to know clearly what you want to do ?

Comment: check my answer and if that solve your problem, make sure to mark it as answer.

Comment: Wel @SilentCoder i tried your solution, but iam getting the next error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noUiSlider' of undefined

Comment: where you getting the error ? in which line ? did you check my fiddle link ?

Comment: @SilentCoder yes i did! I just get the error when i click on a value:
main.js:276 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noUiSlider' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (main.js:276)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Is it working fine in fiddle for you? and can you update your new code with combining my code. since it is working fine in fiddle I can't find any error there. And check you have link nouislider js and jquery. I used some cdn links in fiddle

Comment: The difference between the fiddle and my main code is that the <div class="create-slider"> is hard coded in the fiddle. In my code the div is appended

Comment: That is why may be it is not working. then can you share the that appending code also. Because your question you have not mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

I changes your `JS` code little bit and add style to get cursor.

```
var sliders = $('.create-sliders');
for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {

    noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
        start: [ 0 ],
        range: {
            // start at 0 and end at 1000
            min: 0,
            max: 180
        },
        behaviour: 'snap',  
        connect: [true, false],
        //set values that are clickable
        pips: { mode: 'values', values: [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180] 
        },
    });
    sliders[i].noUiSlider.on('slide', addValues);

}

$('.noUi-value').click(function(){
      var selectedSliderIndex = $(this).parents('.create-sliders').index();
    var value = Number($(this).data('value'));
    sliders[selectedSliderIndex].noUiSlider.set(value);
});

function addValues(){
    var allValues = [];
}
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeagqw7j/1/) for working example.